# how to count how many times a loop was executed?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that prints products of a number, (for example, 2 can be 1 * 4 , 2 * 2 , 4 * 1 and counter shows (3) numbers), I need to have a counter that counts how many numbers were printed. I can't use (i) as a counter as it counts everything.

```
for(i=1; i<=number; i++)
{
    if(number%i==0)
    cout<<i<<"*"<<number/i<<"="<<number<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Create a variable outside your loop and then increment it inside the if statement. You'll need to {} the if statement since it will be multiple lines.

Comment: Add a separate counter variable for the number of lines printed. Increment it when that line is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another variable and expand the body of the if-statement right?

```cpp
int count = 0;
for(i=1; i<=number; i++)
{
  if(number%i==0) {
    cout<<i<<"*"<<number/i<<"="<<number<<endl;
    count++;
  }
}
cout << "Printed " << count << " times" << endl;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `i` is declared outside of the loop, gets initialized to 1, and is already incremented by 1 each iteration, you can just print it out after.

```
int i;
for(i=1; i<=number; i++)
{
    if(number%i==0)
    cout<<i<<"*"<<number/i<<"="<<number<<endl;
}
cout << "Looped " << i << " times\n";
return 0;
```

Just note `i` must be declared outside the loop.